# LINQ & Lambda Expressions equivalent of SQL In

Tags: sql, lambda

Is there a lambda equivalent of IN?  I will like to select all the funds with ids either 4, 5 or 6.  One way of writing it is:

> List fundHistoricalPrices = lionContext.FundHistoricalPrices.Where(fhp => fhp.Fund.FundId == 5 || fhp.Fund.FundId == 6 || fhp.Fund.FundId == 7).ToList();

However, that quickly becomes unmanageable if I need it to match say 100 different fundIds.  Can I do something like:

> List
>   fundHistoricalPrices =
>   lionContext.FundHistoricalPrices.Where(fhp
>   => fhp.Fund.FundId in(5,6,7)).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhere along these lines, but I can't quite agree with the approach you have taken. But this will do if you really want to do this:

```
.Where(fhp => new List<int>{5,6,7}.Contains( fhp.Fund.FundId )).ToList();
```

You may want to construct the List of ids before your LINQ query...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Contains() method on a collection to get the equivalent to `in`.

```
var fundIds = new [] { 5, 6, 7 };

var fundHistoricalPrices = lionContext.FundHistoricalPrices.Where(fhp => fundIds.Contains(fhp.Fund.FundId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method like this :

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
```

Then :

```
List fundHistoricalPrices = lionContext.FundHistoricalPrices.Where(fhp => fhp.Fund.FundId.In(5,6,7)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the only similar operator i'm aware of is the Contains() function.

ANother was is to construct your query dynamically by using the predicate builder out of the LINQkit: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

**Example**

```
int[] fundIds = new int[] { 5,6,7};

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<FundHistoricalPrice>();

foreach (int  id in fundIds)
{
    int tmp = id;
    predicate = predicate.Or (fhp => fhp.Fund.FundId == tmp);
}

var query = lionContext.FundHistoricalPrices.Where (predicate);
```